# Create Images derivates for Hybris Gallery Images Generator and Image Magic

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For Hybris 6.7x it is possible to generate all required images by using ImageMagic and **Gallery Images Generator**. 
Anybode knows where can this Gallery Images Generator be downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Hybris can use image magic OOTB. You need to configure it like below parameters in local.properties.

```
magemagick.bindir=/usr/bin/
imagemagick.configuration.directory=/etc/ImageMagick/
```

After configuration you can use de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator for converting images from impex or java code.